# In spark, how to view n row of data without scanning of whole partition in spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have a hive parquet table (external table on top of s3) which contains 6k partition. In data exploration we want to view the sample data, lets say 1/2/10 record without performing any transformation or action.

Is there a way to restrict only one partition and limit/show n records instead of going through 6k partition(if cluster is small it will take huge amount of time to just print 10 rows). I thought about `mapPartitionsWithIndex` but it still go through all partitions

```scala
def mpwi(index: Int, iter: Iterator[Row]): Iterator = {
  if (index == 1) iter
  else Iterator()
}
```

Comment: you can use the sample() method of a RDD object.

Comment: let me try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You should try `limit`. For example:

```scala
val df = spark.sql("select * from your_table")
df.limit(10).show // Retrieves only 10 rows
```

This should be more performant than loading the full table. If you are not getting the expected performance boost, please paste the logical/physical queryplan here so that we can analyse it. You can do that with `df.explain(true)`

Comment: No, this will not work out. Limit do the full scan before it picks n rows

Comment: Then I am assuming you have some operations more complex than a pure select. As I have stated, the query plan would be useful to help you find a solution.